# Tikz diagrams will not render when combined

Tags: tikz-pgf, xlop

I'm not sure if anyone can see what I am doing wrong here as both diagrams work separately, this first one producing a number line and the second on using opal produces an addition question.

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
    \usepackage{xlop}
    \usepackage{pstricks}

    %--------NumberlineCode---------
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \newcommand{\addsubnumline}[3]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[out=45,in=135,relative,>=stealth]
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]  {\footnotesize $\x$};
    \fill (#1,0) circle (2pt);
    \fill (#2,0) circle (2pt);

    \draw[#3,shorten >=2pt]
    \foreach \i in {#1,...,\number\numexpr#2 - 1\relax}{%
        (\i,0) to (\i+1,0)
    } ; 
    \node[color=OrangeRed] at (#2,-0.75) {\small End};
    \node[color=Cerulean] at (#1,-0.75) {\small Start};

    \node at (\number\numexpr #2/2+#1/2\relax,0.5) {\small Move \number\numexpr#2-  #1\relax\ units to the \emph{right}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    %--------NumberlineCode----------

    \begin{document}

    %-----NumberLine
    \addsubnumline{-4}{2}{->,color=MidnightBlue}

    %--------Addition
    \subsection{Addition}
                    
    \opadd[carryadd=false, resultstyle=\white]{356}{278}
    \opadd[carryadd=false, resultstyle=\blue]{356}{278}
    \opadd[carryadd=true, resultstyle=\blue, carrystyle=\scriptsize\red]{356}{278}

    \end{Document}
```

Sorry I cannot produce a screenshot but as I have said it will not render when I put the two codes together.

Comment: Do I get it right, tag [amsmath] is listed in your code, but not related to the solution? If so: Please delete it.

Comment: Sorry this was just part of a bigger document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After commenting out, what's not necessary, adjusting some color names, the main problem seems to be that your code should end as  `\end{document}% <<< typo` .

Besides that there's something odd about the `\opadd` statements, perhaps a consequence of me commenting out all those packages. And the definition of macro `addsubnumline`, of course. And the `\subsection` for a reason: not defined for `class standalone`.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

%    \usepackage{amsmath}
%    \usepackage{mathtools}
%    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tikz}
%    \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
    \usepackage{xlop}
%    \usepackage{pstricks}

    %--------NumberlineCode---------
%    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \newcommand\addsubnumline[3]{% <<<
    \begin{tikzpicture}[out=45,in=135,relative,>=stealth]
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]  {\footnotesize $\x$};
    \fill (#1,0) circle (2pt);
    \fill (#2,0) circle (2pt);

    \draw[#3,shorten >=2pt]
    \foreach \i in {#1,...,\number\numexpr#2 - 1\relax}{%
        (\i,0) to (\i+1,0)
    } ; 
%    \node[color=OrangeRed] at (#2,-0.75) {\small End};
    \node[color=red] at (#2,-0.75) {\small End};
%    \node[color=Cerulean] at (#1,-0.75) {\small Start};
    \node[color=green] at (#1,-0.75) {\small Start};

    \node at (\number\numexpr #2/2+#1/2\relax,0.5) {\small Move \number\numexpr#2-  #1\relax\ units to the \emph{right}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    %--------NumberlineCode----------

    \begin{document}

    %-----NumberLine
    \addsubnumline{-4}{2}{->,color=blue}%color=MidnightBlue}

    %--------Addition
%    \subsection{Addition}
                    
%    \opadd[carryadd=false, resultstyle=\white]{356}{278}
%    \opadd[carryadd=false, resultstyle=\blue]{356}{278}
%    \opadd[carryadd=true, resultstyle=\blue, carrystyle=\scriptsize\red]{356}{278}

    \end{document}% <<< typo
```

Comment: Thanks the only difference I have made is I needed to use \usepackage{pstricks} for the opadd package, and the typos are so silly for me to spot dyslexia is not conducive to spotting errors when writing code!

Comment: Don't worry, we all face these things from time to time. Well, the class-"typo" is a bit more tricky. Don't worry.